# is it possible to find all the triplets in the given array for the O (n) time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, find, triplet

Given an array of numbers find all such triplets that satisfy the given condition.

Condition: `a[i] < a[j] < a[k]` where `I < j < k`.

it is possible to solve this problem in O (n) time?

This is not home work !!!

Comment: Find them or count them? (I believe finding them in O(n) is impossible since there are O(n^3) such triplets in the worst case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the output (worst case) is a lower bound on the complexity.

Since there are possibly O(n^3) such triplets, the complexity cannot be O(n).

For example if the array is sorted from lowest to highest, you will have n choose 3 such triplets which is order of n^3.

If the question refers to finding the **number** of triplets, here is the most efficient solution I saw:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/count-unique-increasing-subsequences-of-length-3-in-on-log-n

Comment: how do you count the number of triplets in the given array ?

Comment: the source of the problem http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-set-60-internship/   
Question 1:
Given an array of numbers find all such triplets that satisfy the given condition.

The Problem not correctly formulated ?

Comment: I believe it's not formulated correctly. "*find* all the triplets" should be "*count* all the triplets" or "find the number of triplets"

Comment: and how to find the number of triplets ?